# Test Kitchen - How can I pass the local user login in as a Chef attribute?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra, vagrantfile, test-kitchen

Our development environment includes local VMs running queries to larger, shared resources in the cloud.

It was set up in such a way that the local user's login would be passed into a Chef role as an attribute, which is used to define SSH and DB connections.

We currently use Ruby in the Vagrantfile to pluck out the login and vm.provision to create a /tmp file on the guest VM's filesystem.  Our Chef role for the local VMs reads the contents of that file and passes the value into an attribute.

Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

(snip)

require 'etc'
user = Etc.getlogin

(snip)

analytics.vm.provision :shell, inline: "echo #{user} > /tmp/remote_user"
```

During the Chef run, The contents of /tmp/remote_user are read by the following:

```
remote_user = File.open("/tmp/remote_user", "r").read.strip
sandbox = "_#{remote_user}"

default_attributes "remote_user" => remote_user,
    "sandbox" => sandbox,
```

Is there a better way to add the current user's login as an attribute to a local Chef run?

If not, how can I replicate the functionality I had in our old Vagrantfile in a .kitchen.yml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test Kitchen processes `.kitchen.yml` via ERB, so you could just simply put something like this in your ERB file:

```
attributes:
  foo: <%=  ENV['STUFF'] %>
```

And then `node['foo']` would contain `$STUFF`. Switch STUFF to USER in your case.

Comment: Alternately, you could do

    attributes:
      foo: <%= `whoami` %>

to go directly to the username.